# clone PCIe NVME containing Linux partition in dual boot system - any advice?

Tags: clone

I have a dual boot system - Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Windows 11 on regular SSD(2.5 inches) and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on PCIe NVME Gen 1 - 512 GB. As PCIE NVME prices has come down and my usage of linux has increased, I bought another PCIe NVME Gen4 4 TB drive for my linux. My desktop's mother board has provision for only one PCIe NVME drive which means I need to clone 512 GB PCIe NVME to 4 TB PCIe NVME.
Has somebody has done this in the past? Anything to be taken care of?
My linux install is simple - / and swap partition and nothing fancy.
Was going thru this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997789/clone-linux-partition-only-from-dual-boot-16-04-disk-to-make-new-bootable-linux) but it seems there is not much discussed about this.

Comment: I changed from a M.2 SATA SSD to a M.2 NVMe drive. I just did a new install to new NVMe drive & restored (rsynced) from my backups which were on another drive. But then I put M.2 SATA SSD in an adapter M.2 to USB. Almost as fast as when internal drive. The M.2 SATA was a noticable upgrade over HDD. NVMe is faster but not as noticeable improvement as SATA SSD was so much better than HDD. I now will not buy more flash drives as I have many and they now seem so slow.

Comment: any reason why you didn't do the clone? Clonezilla didn't even recognized my PCIE NVME drive(which contains Linux)-though it recognized my new PCIE NVME drive in the enclosure connected via USB.

Comment: I believe in new installs, to houseclean cruft. Often with new drive I do not want exactly same partitions. And when changing drive size, you have to resize/move partitions which requires good backup anyway. And I often am using both drives, duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [AOMEI Assistant Professional edition](https://www.aomeitech.com/pa/professional.html) for this. Clonezilla in Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS didn't recognized my existing PCIE NVME SSD(on which Linux was installed) from which I wanted to transfer my Linux O/S to new PCIE NVME SSD.

It worked flawlessly. Just do sector by sector copy and switch from old PCIE NVME SSD to new PCIE NVME SSD on the computer motherboard.
After that my dual boot worked as it is.

Once within Ubuntu Linux, I unmounted "/" and resized the "/" via gparted.